# HPUX Not allowed to create logical volumes larger than 2TB

Tags: hp-ux

I have 40TB logical volume on HPUX but even after I installed the patch(PHCO_37939) as suggested in this link http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LVM-and-VxVM/Not-allowed-to-create-logical-volumes-larger-than-2TB/td-p/4834031 I still see it as 2TB. Any suggestions ?

```
SCSI describe of /dev/rdsk/c29t0d1:
vendor: COMPELNT
product id: Compellent Vol  
type: direct access
size: 2147483647 Kbytes
bytes per sector: 512
```

Comment: So the LUN is seen by HP-UX correctly. Are you using HP-UX 11.23? LVM or VxVM? If LVM, what does `vgdisplay -v vgXX` and `pvdisplay /dev/dsk/c29t0d1` say?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend/create any logical volume more than 2 TB in HPUX LVM. Max is 2 TB and that too on 11.31 because number of max physical extents (PE) on 11.31 is 65536 and with that max size of PE 32 mb. so total size= 65536*32 mb= 2 TB.

Comment: Just to clear that max PE size is 256Mb but if you choose 65536 total extents PE per PV then you can max take 32Mb PE Size.